# Mem Avail in yarn UI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

What does mean `Mem Avail` in yarn UI?

I set `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` to 1024 and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` to 4096. `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is also set to -1 as default. I can see the memory is free in every nodes and UI show that `Phys Mem Used` is just 14%. However, the `Mem Avail` is 0 B and I don't know what is it and how to increase it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!
It's equal to `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` which is The total amount of memory that YARN can use on **a** given **node**. You might need to set it higher inside `yarn-site.xml` depending on the amount of data you plan on processing.

The default value of this config is 8GB, although with *getconf* command you will see **-1** which doesn't mean total memory of the system.

Before:

> $ hdfs getconf -confKey yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
> -1

After set it in `yarn-site.xml`:

> $ hdfs getconf -confKey yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
> 40960

The result:

[image]